# iterate over a dictionary to create a single json

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I'm trying to generate the resource representation for the bigquery API to insert a new table(/view) into one of our databases.  My overall approach to doing this was to create the header of the json (everything prior to the schema elements, i.e. things that don't need to be iterated over), the footer of the json (everything after the schema elements), and the middle part of the json.  So my overall question is how do I combine a bunch of individual JSONs together to create a single JSON? (e.g. output json = headerJson + bodyJson + footerJson)

And as a sub-question within that, how do I create the body section of the json.  My approach was to iterate over the list of items in the dict, use the key and value in the dict to populate the json, and then append each of these individual elements into a dictionary that I could then convert into a string.

e.g.

```
def generateFieldJsonForSchema(d, query, db="defaultDb", dataset="dataset", tableId="table"):
    jsonDict=[]

    for name, type in d.iteritems():

        jsonDict.append(str(json.dumps({"name":name, "type":type, "mode":"NULLABLE"})))

    return jsonDict
```

However when I do this and try to convert the resulting output back into a string and then dump it back into a json (e.g. json.dumps(str(','.join(outputtedJson))) ), I get each of the elements in the json double escaped.  So I understand (or maybe I don't...) that you get that result when you try to dump a json that's already a json, but in this case I have a list of individual jsons, instead of a single json.

Unless a list of jsons is a json.  Sorry if I'm a moron.

Comment: Can you give us a copy of the original dictionary from which you're creating the JSON file? Then I might be able to help you more.

Answer (score 1):

Build a *Python object* containing all the parts, then convert that object to JSON. Don't concatenate different JSON objects:

```
def generateFieldJsonForSchema(d, query, db="defaultDb", dataset="dataset", tableId="table"):
    objects = []

    for name, type in d.iteritems():
        objects.append({"name": name, "type": type, "mode": "NULLABLE"})

    return objects
```

The function returns a *Python list* containing dictionaries. Add other objects to that list (your header and footer), then convert that list to JSON at the last possible moment:

```
fields = generateFieldJsonForSchema(input_dictionary, query)
final_results = [header_object] + fields + [footer_object]
json_result = json.dumps(final_results)
```